# Unexpected behaviour with PHP arrays

Tags: php, syntax

As you can't have an array in a define or a class constant I thought I'd create an abstract class for configuration data for my project that needs to be more structures than simple values.

At first I thought I'd try something like the following, but this resulted in a syntax error on line 6:

```
<?php
abstract class Config
{
    static private
        $paths  = array (
            'classes' . _DS . 'cmsItems',
            'classes' . _DS . 'dbdrivers',
            'classes' . _DS . 'core'
        );

    static public function getPaths ()
    {
        return self::$paths;
    }
}
?>
```

I then tried defining a static array inside the getter instead of a private property.

```
<?php
abstract class Config
{
    static public function getPaths ()
    {
        static $paths   = array (
            'classes' . _DS . 'cmsItems',
            'classes' . _DS . 'dbdrivers',
            'classes' . _DS . 'core'
        );
        return $paths;
    }
}
?>
```

This just resulted in a syntax error on line 7

But if I removed the static keyword...

```
<?php
abstract class Config
{
    static public function getPaths ()
    {
        $paths  = array (
            'classes' . _DS . 'cmsItems',
            'classes' . _DS . 'dbdrivers',
            'classes' . _DS . 'core'
        );
        return $paths;
    }
}
?>
```

This seems to work fine (except now the array is created every time the function runs, which seems a bit wasteful to me).

Can anybody explain what's going on here?

(FYI, _DS is defined elsewhere and is simply an alias to DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the page [**Static Keyword**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) :

> Like any other PHP static variable,
>   static properties may only be
>   initialized using a literal or
>   constant; **expressions are not
>   allowed**.

Yes, just after that, it is said :

> So while **you may initialize a static
>   property to an** integer or **array**
>   (for instance), you may not initialize
>   it to another variable, to a function
>   return value, or to an object.

But, still, **expressions are forbidden**.

When using this :

```
static private
    $paths  = array (
        'classes' . _DS . 'cmsItems',
        'classes' . _DS . 'dbdrivers',
        'classes' . _DS . 'core'
    );
```

You are having expressions in there -- I'm thinking about the strings concatenations : the content of your array is not constant, it is not known at compile time *(one cannot know it just looking at this portion of code)*.

If you **remove those expressions**, and your code looks like this *(for example ; I just replaced the concatenations with a `_` in the strings)* :

```
static private
    $paths  = array (
        'classes_cmsItems',
        'classes_dbdrivers',
        'classes_core'
    );
```

There will be no expression -- and, so, no error.

Answer (score 0):

From : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

"Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object."

Your line : `'classes' . _DS . 'cmsItems'` is an expression, and thus the error.